# Is it possible to have git submodules that are always at HEAD without requiring any update commits?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Currently, as part of the build process in a repository I'm working on, several repositories are cloned into a subdirectory of said repository. When it comes to commit time, those repositories are ignored through the .gitignore. I would like to implement these through submodules, but from my understanding it seems that submodules have to be manually updated to match HEAD?

Is it possible to set up the submodules in such a way that they are only mentioned in the .gitmodules file, **not in the path they are cloned into**, and, when the repository is cloned recursively, will be at HEAD?

Comment: Short answer: no. That's not how submodules work.

Comment: Your original build process is what I would suggest instead of submodules, if you want all those repos to be at origin/HEAD automatically.

Comment: Ah, okay. Shame.